# NMOS Circuit analysis where the drain and gate are the same

Tags: mosfet, nmos, saturation

I was trying to solve the following circuit where I have to calculate I_DS and V_DS in the following circuit. [image: circuit exercise]

So the first thing I noticed, since that the gate and drain are connected, is that this is NMOS is in saturation because: $$V_{G} = V_D => V_{GS} = V_{DS} => V_{DS} \ge V_{DS,sat} => V_{DS}\ge V_{DS} - V_{TH}$$ So it will always be true that it is in saturation. However I am not sure how to continue the exercise from this assumption. I know the gate has no current flowing through it, however I don't know how I could calculate the voltage over the resistor. I tried using $$I_{DS} = K * (V_{GS} - V_{TH})^2$$ with $$K=0.2 mA/V^2, V_{TH} = 1.5V$$ However since I do not know Vgs nor how to calculate it I wanted to ask for some help to point me the right way.

Comment: If there is some current flowing through the resistor, what is the **minimum** value of \$V_{GS}\$? What happens if \$V_{GS}\$ is greater than that minimum value?

Comment: Is the minimum value of Vgs equal too Vth?

Comment: Do the KVL  \$V_{DD} = V_{GS} + I_{DS}*R\$

Comment: @G36 would Vgs be equal to 6V?

Comment: No, you have two equations one for Ids current and the second one from KVL.  All you need to do is to combine those two equations into one equation.  Can you do it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got to the solution!

Comment: My solution is [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=6+%3D+x+%2B+0.2*%28x+-+1.5%29%5E2*2+)  Vgs ≈ 3.83V and Ids ≈ 1mA

Comment: Could you answer your own question below?